# How to get env.php variables in Magento 2 inside php

Tags: magento, magento2

I wanna get app/etc/env.php variables in Magento 2 inside php code.

how is it possible?

for example I wanna something like this:

```
<?php
echo $_ENV['db']['host'];
?>
```

I mean I need to get the host that had been set in the env.php file.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @AdamS. yes, thanks btw buddy. but it wans't what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer here: [Magento 2. Retrieve information from env.php programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/215781/41707)

Basically you want to inject `\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig` and then use its `get()` method:

```php
/**
 * Gets data from flattened data
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @param mixed $defaultValue
 * @return mixed|null
 */
public function get($key = null, $defaultValue = null)
```

[GitHub Source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php#L68)

For example: `$deploymentConfig->get('db/connection/default/host');`

Additional: [env.php reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/config-reference-envphp.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declared the values for that env param first.

You can do it in the *.php file like that:

```
$_ENV["MY_ENV_VALUE"] = "value";
$value = $_ENV["MY_ENV_VALUE"];
```

If your're using apache declare env in .htaccess like that:

```
SetEnv MY_ENV_VALUE "value"
```

If you're using nginx you need to use fastcgi_params and set `variables_order = "EGPCS"` in your php.ini file.

```
fastcgi_param MY_ENV_VALUE "value"
```